# Can Pandas (or Python) recognize today's date?

Tags: date, pandas

I was wondering if Pandas can somehow figure out what today's date is allowing me to automate the naming of the html file I create when I use the  "df.to_html"  method. 
Basically I"m trying to read a website using method   "pd.read_html", and then save the dataframe as an html file, daily. The name of the html file will be the day's date. (So today is 9/28/2016 and tomorrow will be 10/01/16 and so on ) I'm not particular about the format of the date, so Sept or 09, whichever is okay. 
I'm trying to automate this as much as possible, and so far the best I've gotten is, using  ".format"  which allows me some flexiblity. But I don't know how I can further automate the process.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('random site')
today_date = 'saved data/{}.html'.format('Sept 28')    # I'm saving it in the folder "saved data" with the name as today's date.html. 
df.to_html(today_date)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

specifically: `datetime.date.today().isoformat()` gives you a string with the current date in ISO 8601 format (‘YYYY-MM-DD’)

Comment: Thanks! I had browsed through the datetime module but I didn't know about the .isfoformat, which is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: That's why we are here ^_^

Comment: `.isoformat()` is just one of a ton of possible formats, you can do your own with `strftime(format)`

Comment: I took a look at strfime(format) but I'm having a little trouble understanding it. Where exactly do I insert the directive? 

today =dt.date.today().strftime(%c)

Seems to be incorrect.

Comment: IIRC you need to give it a string so you can't just put %c it has to be "%c"